# How to get related object in CollectionType in Symfony4

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony4

Please, could you explain how to get the object in the child form in CollectionType way (embedded form)?

The parent form is this one:

```
class ClienteRespuestasType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        dump ($options['data']);
        $builder
            ->add('respuestas', CollectionType::class, array(
                // each entry in the array will be an "email" field
                'entry_type' => RespuestaType::class,
                // these options are passed to each "email" type
                'entry_options' => array(
                    'attr' => array('class' => 'email-box'),
                )
            ))

            ->add('Guardar', SubmitType::class, array(
                'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-default'),
            ));
        }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Cliente::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The child form is the one below. The `$options['data']` is null.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    dump ($options['data']);
    $builder
        ->add('contestacion', null, array(
            'label' => 'HOW TO GET ATTRIBUTE OF THIS CHILD FORM'
        ))
    ;
}
```

And the relation between classes Cliente and Respuesta:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Respuesta", mappedBy="cliente", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $respuestas;
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does the class Cliente() look like?

Comment: How about just render the form in your browser, then inspect the element you are looking for?

Comment: I updated to add the part of the class Cliente that is related with class Respuesta...